# Changes in data after game was inactive

Tags: iphone, ios, coronasdk

I'm starting to work on an app similar to tamagotchi (virtual pet kind of stuff) in the Corona SDK. I got absolutely stuck and am out of ideas on how to get one part.

How can the game character, lets say "pet" change its status, e.g. become hungry or die while the game is inactive? Or maybe its possible to make the changes as the player enters the game the next time, maybe to bind it to the global time (still no idea of how to do it)?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can think is to keep all relevant data in a file. The first datum would be a time stamp of the last time the game was turned inactive.

Every time the game is first activated it reads the file along with the time stamp. After a specific time length has passed the pet becomes hungry, tired, etc. If an extraordinary long time has passed the pet dies.

You can go further by putting a time stamp next to each datum like "last fed", "last watered", etc. and then you can make individual attributes expire at different times, including death by boredom by keeping the global "last active" time and if a long time has passed without running the game the pet dies.

Comment: Thanks! I got the global idea. Do you think I should do it via the OS time? Something like:                                lastFed.osDate=19.00;                                newGame.osDate=22.00;                                     noFoodTime=3.00; hunger=noFoodTime*HungerPerHour;                         I know I am being nooby as hell :) Anyway, is the idea right?

Comment: to be more precise hungerLoad = hungerMax - (noFoodTime*HungerPerHour);

Comment: Whatever works and is the easiest to parse. Truth be told, I don't own an iPhone nor do I use Corona; but from a game-development stand-point the above solution is the easiest. Though I'd be careful getting the time directly from the OS, can't users change the time manually? They might break the game or accidentally kill their pet if the time you calculate goes negative.

Comment: Yes, that problem also comes to my mind, but than I don't really know what api to use to complete the task. Thanks anyway, probably some corona user will help on this task too :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually created an application like this. I created a number of states in a enum and then in a checkMoodState method I hardcoded the values that decided the state of the mood.

e.g.

- timeSinceLastPlay
- timeSinceLastFeed

or whatever.

Either write the dates to a plist for each variable you want to track and on each check or store them in NSUserDefaults(one function to write them all, one to load them all), subtract the current time from it. You will be left with a negative number, and you can just get its absolute value.

You decide whenever you want to check the last time since whatever it is you are checking, e.g. feeding. Create an NSTimer with the duration of the time between checks and in the method called by the timer, you do you checks and update the mood as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Wanted to ask you, as far as I understand (you said you used NSTimer) you created your app in Obj-C. Do you think in an app like this it would be superior to lua? I'm asking because my obj-c knowledge is even worse than the simple-to-use lua :)

Comment: "an app like this" -  Do you mean in objective-C?  Im not sure on the performance of lua tbh. If I had to guess I would think any native language would be superior to an interpreted scripting language, Im not sure what it gets broken down to on iOS, maybe C, if anything. I really have zero knowledge on languages running on iOS other than C, objective-c, (tiny bit of c++). Objective-C is a nice language imo ;)

Comment: `(one function to write them all, one to load them all)` ... and in the darkness `late-bind` them....Sorry, couldn't resist. :P

Comment: Helium3: "app like this" - the tamagotchi one. "Do you think in an app like this (tamagotchi) it (objc) would be superior to lua" sorry for being hard to understand =p

Comment: I think it would be superior to use the native language. I actually searched for some benchmarks on performance between lua and obj-c after your previous comment. Seems like lua is has a slightly larger footprint. That could be an isolated incident. Like I said I have no idea. If I had to give my advice, I would say learn objective-C. You will have the freedom to do more than a framework sitting on top of iOS can provide. Can you code in C?